# How woud you plan a sector directory with Drupal?

Tags: entities

I have to realize a sector directory, a directory of restaurants, bars, wineyardsm, carpenter...

So each sector has it's own properties like the menu card or something else. But there are properties like the name, address, telephone number etc. which are the same in for each sector.

I thougt to realize it so: 1 node type: Business (Fields: title, address, city, telephone number...); for each sector one content type with the special fields like the menu card or the wine list; to connect these two nodes i thougt to use the Relation module

What do you think of my plan? Is it used to do it like this or are there other solutions? One problem of my plan would be the backend. I have to edit/create two nodes for one business. For the normal user it would be too complicate. Is there a way to edit the connected node on the same page?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Reference entity http://drupal.org/project/entityreference will let you make all the relations you need.

Also, instead of use node I will create my own entities (http://www.istos.it/blog/drupal/drupal-entities-part-1-moving-beyond-nodes) and all the connections with views.

And remember that taxonomies also are Entities, so you can create a Vocabulary that it's "Sector", and every Sector add all the fields you need.

It'll harder but it'll improve the performance.

Oskar